# 4-bit Enum in C#

Tags: c#, interop, struct, pinvoke

I know that its possible to make enums that use signed or unsigned 64, 32, 16, and 8 bit values as their underlying valud type using (:ulong, :uint, :ushort, :byte).  But is it possible to create a 4 bit enum?

(I'm writing some code that will interop with C++ and the struct that I have in C# for a return type has one field that would be most natural as a 4-bit struct.)

Comment: I think your processor will not find a 4-bit value natural in any way.

Comment: Wouldn't something like that be padded to a larger width or am I way off?

Comment: @Chaos: You are not mistaken. The smallest size that's "natural" for Intel's is 8 bits. What Michael wants is possible, but is best done by combining two limited-range 8-bit enums together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C# spec:

> The approved types for an enum are
>   `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`,
>   `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`.

None of these are 4-bit types. You'd have the same problem on the C++ side as well.

Comment: C++ has bit fields. You can say how many bits a struct field uses.

Comment: Yeah, on the C++ side, its just a matter of doing ":4" in the struct and then they #define the 16 possible values.  It's easy here on the C# side just to merge two of these :4 values into one byte.  But then I have to look at the lower 4 bits of it and the upper 4 bits separately.

Answer (score 1):

> But is it possible to create a 4 bit enum?

No, mostly because that would be awkward and slow. And syntactically there exists no 4-bit type to specify as base type.

> with C++ and the struct that I have in C# for a return type has one field that would be most natural as a 4-bit struct.

I doubt that very much, C++ can deal with bit fields but this is very efficient (except maybe in space).

Interop with C++ is difficult enough, when the return-type is your choice then don't make it any harder than it has to be.

Comment: Why would a 4-bit signed and unsigned value types be more or less awkward and slow than 8-bit or 16-bit types?  Both are less than the memory size of the machines (32 or 64 bit).

Comment: Also, it would be very natural here because in C++, they have a UInt8 that they've divided into two 4-bit fields using the :4 syntax.  Both represent 16 possible states of X and Y.  In my C# struct, I would like to have two 4-bit fields representing the states of X and Y.  Instead, I have to have a single UInt8 (byte) field that represents the state of X and Y together.

Comment: @Michael, Byte is the smallest addressable unit on most hardware, and about as fast as the native 32/64 bit words. For 4 bits, the compiler has to insert extra masking operations.